# Getting the standard output from CD into a file within a loop

Tags: batch-file

Using some components I found here, I have built a batch file to loop through a directory tree starting from the directory where the batch file runs.

The batch file works as expected but I need to capture the output from the cmd.exe command `CD` into a file that I created earlier in the run.

The problem is that if I attempt to redirect the standard output into the .txt file I only see the first found directory.

I have found some code which uses PowerShell, to pull the listing from the Command Prompt screen, but to me this is inelegant, *(although it seems to work)*.

I have read the material on `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` but it appears to be above my paygrade as I haven't been able to make it work.

The working code is below, with a `Rem`ark where I think the export to the .txt file should go.

Help would be appreciated.

```
Rem  Recursively Traverse a Directory Tree

Rem  Notes:
Rem  "For /r" command can be used to recursively visit all the directories in
Rem  a directory tree and perform a command in each subdirectory.
Rem  In this case, save the output to a text file

Rem  for /r = Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
Rem  pushd  = Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for
Rem           use by the POPD command.
Rem  popd   = Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD
Rem           command.

@echo off
CLS
echo.
echo.
Rem  FirstJob - Generate a date and save in the work file. 

Rem Grab the date/time elements and stuff them into a couple of variables
set D=%date%
set T=%time%
set DATETIME=%D% at %T%
Rem  OK. We now have the date and time stuffed into the variable DATETIME
Rem  so now stick it into our work file along with a heading.
 Echo List of Found Directories > DirList.txt
 Echo %DATETIME% >> DirList.txt
 echo. >> DirList.txt
 echo. >> Dirlist.txt

Rem  SecondJob - Do the looping stuff and save found directories to file.

Rem  Start at the top of the tree to visit and loop though each directory
for /r %%a in (.) do (
Rem  enter the directory
 pushd %%a
 CD

Rem ------------------  direct Standard Output to the file DirList.txt -----------------

Rem  exit the directory
 popd
)

: END
Rem  All finished
Echo Done!
exit /b
```

The additional lines of code when added to the above scrip before the :END marker. which did produce the wanted output were:

```
powershell -c "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('^a')
powershell -c "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('^c')
powershell Get-Clipboard>>DirList.txt
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `CD` command inside the `FOR /R`?  You are already doing a `PUSHD` so there is no point in using the `CD` command.  The `FOR` variable is now your current working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `pushd` command, because you change the current directory, the file `dirlist.txt` must use an absolute path, else you create it in every `pushed` directory.
I used `%~dp0` here, it's the path of the batch file itself.

You could try

```
cd >> %~dp0\dirlist.txt
```

Or just

```
echo %%a >> %~dp0\dirlist.txt
```

Or you could use a single redirecton of the complete bock

```
( 
  for /r %%a in (.) do (
    pushd %%a
    echo %%a
    popd
  )
) > dirlist.txt
```

Comment: And @Squashman is absolutely correct in the reason for the use of CD.

Comment: The use of CD is the reason it was included and why the additional code works. If there was no output to the Command screen then no data would be gathered.  I would prefer a more elegant solution than a coded snatch and grab, but I haven't been able to make that work as I don't yet fully grasp the arcane machinations of standard output in a loop.

Comment: @JRinOz There is no difference in the output of `cd` to `echo %%a`, because you changed to the diretory `%%a`. But absolute paths are required

Comment: Thanks jeb, I'll try that. Some of my comments are out of order in the time frame of answers and comments, possibly due to the sloooow National Broadband Network rolled out by our Government. so I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: Thank you Jeb.  Worked just fine.   Problem solved.

Comment: @JRinOz if your problem was solved by this answer, you need to select it as the correct answer by ticking the grey `✓` on the left of the answer, so it becomes green.